# can I confirm whether or not someone tweeted a link

Tags: twitter, tweets

I've added the tweet button (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) to my website and I'm trying to determine whether or not someone tweeted a link. Any ideas on whether this can be done and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tweet button allows you to create [javascript event listeners](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events).

Also, please note that in most cases it's [not allowed by Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/api-terms) to give something to a user after tweeting, making it a requirement to send spam.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I also appreciate the link to the terms. I'll modify my post and carefully read through that. Cheers!